# Draw Regions On the Complex Plane that Satisfy this Relation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

I'm looking to draw a region that satisfies the following:

$$ Im\left(\frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2}\right)=0 $$

What I know so far is this: the expression as it's given is not of the form $ a + bi $, as there's an imaginary part in the denominator. Therefore, my thought was to multiply the expression by the complex conjugate of the denominator first:

$$ \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_2} * \frac{\bar z-\bar z_2 }{\bar z-\bar z_2} $$
$$ = \frac{z\bar z - z\bar z_2 - z_1\bar z + z_1\bar z_2}{|z-z_2|^2} $$
$$ = \frac{|z|^2 - z\bar z_2 - z_1\bar z + z_1\bar z_2}{|z-z_2|^2} $$

Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Hint: the quotient of two (nonzero) complex numbers is real if and only if the two numbers lie on a common line through the origin.

Comment: Beat me to it. My hint was going to be: if a complex number has imaginary part zero, it's argument must also be 0.

Comment: Hint. Let $(z-z_1)/(z-z_2)=r\in R.$  Solve for $z.$